# "Non-communicative protocol" vs. "non-communication protocol"

Tags: grammar, american-english, formal-language

I am trying to say that in an experiment I prohibited users from communicating with each other. Which one is correct?

> 1. We imposed a non-communication protocol.
> 2. We imposed a non-communicative protocol.

Or instead of *non-...* can I use *communication-less*?

Comment: I would not use *non-* there. I'd go with "no-communication protocol."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**uncommunicative** means "to not speak or otherwise communicate; to remain silent and unresponsive". Thus, to call the protocol itself **uncommunicative** would be a kind of "short-hand" or casual usage, as it is the test subjects who are told not to communicate, to remain uncommunicative.

The natural way to say this is:

> We told the users not to communicate.

The "technical-jargon" version might be:

> A non-communication protocol was imposed upon the users.

or as Robusto suggested:

> A "no-communication" protocol was in effect in this experiment.

though I think if you're going to try to make the jargon less jargony and more natural-sounding, you might as well state the matter idiomatically to begin with:

> The users were told not to communicate with each other.

Comment: +1 .. Or, if noncommunication was imposed by means other than injunction, "The users were prevented from communicating with each other".